# launch MPI cluster failed

Tags: ssh, mpi, mpich

I tried to launch my MPI cluster. And I have disabled the firewall with `sudo ufw disable` on every node. I have setup passwordless connection so that pc0 can connect pc1 and pc2 via ssh passwordlessly.

The ub0 is the master node host, ub1 and ub2 are slave nodes.

The error is:

```
pc0@ub0:~/Downloads/mpich-3.0.4/examples$ mpirun -n 10 -f servers ./cpi
[proxy:0:1@ub1] HYDU_sock_connect (./utils/sock/sock.c:140): unable to get host address for ub0 (1)
[proxy:0:1@ub1] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:189): unable to connect to server ub0 at port 36272 (check for firewalls!)
[proxy:0:2@ub2] HYDU_sock_connect (./utils/sock/sock.c:140): unable to get host address for ub0 (1)
[proxy:0:2@ub2] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:189): unable to connect to server ub0 at port 36272 (check for firewalls!)
```

the servers file is:

```
ub0:2
pc1@ub1:2
pc2@ub2:2
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 i386. MPI is MPICH

Now, I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not add IP and hostname into `/etc/hosts` on other nodes.

So edit `/etc/hosts`, and add ip and hostname like this:

```
192.168.0.1 node1
192.168.0.2 node2
192.168.0.3 node3
```

After that, copy the compiled file to corresponding directory in other nodes. Then it will work fine.